# $R(\theta)=151250\sin(2\theta) $ Find angle of inclination of gun.

Tags: trigonometry

The Range of a particular projectile is given by $R(\theta)=151250\sin(2\theta)$ , where $R$ is measured in feet and theta is the angle of inclination of the gun barrel. Determine theta in degrees to hit a target $5000$ feet away from the gun.

So far I have this:

$$\sin(2\theta)=\frac{5000}{151250}$$
$$\sin(2\theta)=0.033058$$
Then
$$2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) = .033058$$ 
$$\cos(\theta) = .033058 \vee  2\sin(\theta) = .033058$$
So
$$\sin^{-1}(.016529) = .947081^{\circ} $$
$$\cos^{-1}(.033058) = 88.1056^{\circ} $$

Not sure where to go from here, think I did something wrong by splitting it up as well.

Comment: The problem is in the split you could assume  if ab=c then $a=c$ or $b=c$ only if $c=0$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin(2\theta)=\frac{5000}{151250}$$
$$2\theta=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{5000}{151250}\right)$$
$$\theta=\frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{5000}{151250}\right)$$

Comment: Bear in mind that there are two acceptable values for$$\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{5000}{151250}\right)$$